# Spinner and page reset after views.py completes processing in Django

Tags: javascript, css, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a Django web application where users can generate and download Excel files. To provide feedback to users while the file is being generated, I've implemented a spinner animation using HTML and JavaScript. However, I'm facing difficulty in stopping the spinner animation after the file download is complete.

Here's my HTML and JavaScript code for the spinner:

```
<style>
.spinner-container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.spinner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-left-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
</style>

<button type="submit" onclick="showSpinner()">GENERATE</button>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner-container">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>

<script>
function showSpinner() {
    document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
}

function hideSpinner() {
    document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

And here's my Django views.py code for downloading the file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as pd

def downloadFile(request):
    try:
        # Generate the Excel file
        with pd.ExcelWriter('NEW-DOWNLOAD.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as excel_file_path:
            # Write dataframes to sheets
            dataframes = {
                'SUMMARY': data,
                'CHART': CHART
            }
            for sheet_name, df in dataframes.items():
                df.to_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=True)

        # Read the entire file as bytes
        with open('NEW-DOWNLOAD.xlsx', 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()

        # Create an HttpResponse with the Excel file as attachment
        response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=NEW-DOWNLOAD.xlsx'

        return response

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error:', e)
        return None

downloaded_response = downloadFile()
if downloaded_response:
    return downloaded_response
else:
    context = {"message": "Error downloading file!"}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

How can I modify this code to stop the spinner animation after the file download is complete? I've tried various approaches, but none of them seem to work reliably. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!